# Nifi Consume AMQP parameterise queue name

Tags: apache-nifi

I am using NIfi for data ingestion. My one of the component consumes the rabit MQ queue using **Consume AMQP** processor.

It's works without any issue however the problem is Queue name. It's different for each and every environment and so I can't run the Nifi Flow without changing the queue name. Which is creating a problem in **QA** and **PROD** environment as I can't change the anything in nifi flow. (it's not allowed)

The Solution I thought it something like this.

- As The queue name is available in a file ( location would be same across all the env)
- Read the file though GetFile processor
- Extract the text through ExtractText Processor
- Give this as a input parameter to ConsumeAMQP processor

The problem is ConsumeAMQP processor doesn't take any input. Would someone please let me know how to do this ?

[image]

Comment: ConsumeAMQP doesn't have upstream connection so you cannot put your result into that processor

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Variable Registry](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/user-guide.html#Variables_Window) included in Apache NiFi to satisfy this use case. The VR contains process group-scoped variables that can be referenced anywhere Expression Language is parsed and can be used for environment-specific variable population.

1. Right-click on the canvas and select "Variables" from the context menu to load the Variable Registry interface.
2. Add a new variable definition by clicking the "**+**" icon. Name it `amqp_queue_name` and provide the desired value *This is the queue name in dev*.
3. Click "Apply" to save this.
4. Configure the `ConsumeAMQP` processor as you normally would, but provide the *Queue* as `${amqp_queue_name}`.

The `ConsumeAMQP` processor will now reference the queue specified in the Variable Registry, dependent on the environment. For example, if you export this template and import it into a *QA* or *Prod* environment where that variable has a different value, it will use whatever is present. This also works with the *versioned flows* concept introduced in NiFi 1.5.0.